# MVC Default binder not binding a nested class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'm having trouble getting the MVC default binder to serialize a nested object.
I've done quite a bit of research to try and figure out what I'm doing wrong, but I'm not seeing it.

The model comes in with all nested objects created (courtesy of the constructors, without them nothing is created) but no data is serialized.

I've overridden the DefaultBinder and added breakpoints to figure out what is failing. It seems to recognize Start and End as DateTimePart, but doesn't do anything with them.

I spent a lot of time trying to read and understand the logic of the DefaultBinder and everything I've read seems to indicate this should work, yet it doesn't. Any help or wild guesses would be appreciated as this is driving me nuts.

Also, to make it clear, I realize I can use a custom binder to overcome this, but before I do I want to understand why this doesn't work with the default binder.

Here's the controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    // GET: Test
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        StartEndTime se = new StartEndTime();
        se.Start = new DateTimeParts();
        se.End = new DateTimeParts();
        se.Start.Date = new DateTime(2015, 2, 22, 13, 12, 0);
        se.End.Date = new DateTime(2015, 3, 1, 10, 43, 0);
        return View(se);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(StartEndTime se)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Here's the view (example only, replicates the issue, but the real one treats time and date differently)

```
@model Models.StartEndTime

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Start.DatePart)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Start.TimePart)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.End.DatePart)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.End.TimePart)

    @Html.SButtonSave()
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Relevant part of generated HTML:

```
<input name="Start_DatePart" id="Start_DatePart" class="text-box single-line form-control datepicker" type="text" value="2015-02-22">
<input name="Start_TimePart" id="Start_TimePart" class="text-box single-line form-control datepicker" type="text" value="0001-01-01">
<input name="End_DatePart" id="End_DatePart" class="text-box single-line form-control datepicker" type="text" value="2015-03-01">
<input name="End_TimePart" id="End_TimePart" class="text-box single-line form-control datepicker" type="text" value="0001-01-01">
```

And finally the model. I've included everything since I'm not sure what is causing the issue:

```
public class DateTimeParts
{
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DatePart
    {
        get
        {
            if (Date.HasValue)
                return Date.Value.Date;
            else
                return null;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.HasValue)
            {
                if (Date.HasValue)
                    Date = value.Value.Date.Date + Date.Value.TimeOfDay;
                else
                    Date = value.Value.Date.Date;
            }
            else
            {
                Date = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public DateTime? TimePart
    {
        get
        {
            if (Date.HasValue)
                return new DateTime() + Date.Value.TimeOfDay;
            else
                return null;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.HasValue)
            {
                if (Date.HasValue)
                    Date = Date.Value.Date + value.Value.TimeOfDay;
                else
                    Date = new DateTime() + value.Value.TimeOfDay;
            }
            else
            {
                Date = new DateTime();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class StartEndTime
{
    public DateTimeParts Start { get; set; }

    public DateTimeParts End { get; set; }

    public int Minutes
    {
        get
        {
            if (!Start.Date.HasValue || !End.Date.HasValue)
                return 0;
            else
                return (int)(End.Date.Value - Start.Date.Value).TotalMinutes;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!Start.Date.HasValue)
                return;
            End.Date = Start.Date.Value + new TimeSpan(0, value, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure of your actual problem, but why do you need a class called `DateTimeParts`, the .net `DateTime` already handles dates and times.

Comment: post your startEndTime class also

Comment: Assume you have some typos in the html - it would be `name="Start.DatePart"` (not `name="Start_DatePart"`) etc.

Comment: To answer the comments:  1.I wanted the binder to bind one field to the date and the other to the time. Need that in my model for that to work. (Could have used two datetimes but that seems clunky.   2. Startendtime class is in the post above, just scroll down.  3. .net 4.5 and new mvc uses underscores instead of dots. The name is generated by microsoft mvc code.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, you had the answer. I use my own custom editors and I stupidly used the Id in the name field. I was under the impression that they always matched (and that the binder used the ID field) but once I used hiddenfor to test, I saw that the name uses dots (.) and the id uses underscores. Now works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet it's the way C# handles `DateTime`. For example, `0001-01-01` doesn't look like a valid date, and it's missing the time stamp.

You should make it set the `value` to something like:

```
string dateString = "5/1/2008 8:30:52 AM";
```

I think the default binder will pick it up then. Use `@Html.HiddenFor` to test it out.

Comment: Actually I use that format in other places with datetimes and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion of using HiddenFor, it helped me find my issue which turned out to be the name of the field as was suggested above.